# I imported both the rig and baked animation seperatly from Maya, but it's not working correctly

Tags: unity, animation, maya, fbx, import

I am using the animation controller to bind the "jump" animation I did onto the rig itself. I don't get any errors. The animation plays. Except it seems to only affect the root joint only. Basically the model moves but not the arms or legs. They stay static. So If i have a character jumping few feet away, the entire model rig will move in jump motion(X and Y axis), but nothing happens with legs and arms.

What's going on?

Comment: We know you imported from Maya, but what did you import *into*? And how did you set up this animation controller?

Comment: Unity 3D. Sorry I thought I mentioned it before. I right clicked in the asset folder and created the animation controller, as you normally would. Then I linked my fbx jump animation to the controller and then linked the controller to the actual rig model.  Animation plays out but the rig stays in T-pose. Arms and legs don't move at all when they should be.

Comment: Are you using a skinned mesh renderer? Show us how you've set up your object and animations so we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Sure thing. Here is the video in play. https://unityguy.tinytake.com/sf/Mjg4MDE2NV84NjQyODUw

Comment: here are individual screen shots. https://ibb.co/k4kgf9
https://ibb.co/cUG9YU
https://ibb.co/msa3tU
https://ibb.co/eLSSL9
https://ibb.co/fPV3tU

Comment: I have solved the problem. The issue was the binded rig itself. Every time I exported it as FBX, it unbinds the mesh and skeleton. That was why it was not working. I solved it by importing the FBX file back in Maya and re-binding the mesh and skeleton and re-exporting it as FBX. That was it.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as an Answer so it can be Accepted and attract up-votes. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The issue was the binded rig/model itself. Every time I exported it as FBX in Maya, it unbinds the mesh and skeleton. That was why the animation was not properly working in Unity.

I solved it by importing the FBX file back in Maya and re-binding the mesh and skeleton and re-exporting it as FBX. That was it.